# When should I use setUpClass and when __init__?

Tags: python, oop, unit-testing

Is there any runtime-logic difference between these two methods? Or any behviour differences?
If not, then should I forget about `__init__` and use only `setUpClass` thinking here about unittests classes like about namespaces instead of language OOP paradigm?

Answer (score 22):

The two are quite different.

`setUpClass` is a class method, for one, so it'll only let you set *class* attributes.

They are also called at different times. The test runner creates *a new instance* for *every test*. If your test class contains 5 test methods, 5 instances are created and `__init__` is called 5 times.

`setUpClass` is normally called only *once*. (If you shuffle up test ordering and test methods from different classes are intermingled, `setUpClass` can be called multiple times, use `tearDownClass` to clean up properly and that won't be a problem).

Also, a test runner usually creates all test instances at the start of the test run; this is normally cheap, as test instances don't hold (much) state so won't take up much memory.

As a rule of thumb, you should *not* use `__init__` at all. Use `setUpClass` to create state shared between all the tests, and use `setUp` to create per-test state. `setUp` is called just before a test is run, so you can avoid building up a lot of memory-intensive state until it is needed for a test, and not before.

Comment: Are there any hooks to run code when the unittests start running?  Like a module-level hook?  I'm looking to load some expensive data and am getting warnings about calling multiprocessing outside __main__ after Py3 upgrade, but I'd rather not delay until `setUpClass` is called.

Comment: I also read that this particular warning shouldn't actually crop up on Unix systems at all due to the support for fork (which doesn't require calling the module with a different __name__), but it is showing on OSX.  Curious if you have any insights on this Martijn?

Comment: @DylanYoung you can always use [`unittest.main()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.main) to control when tests start. Or use the [`setUpModule()` and `tearDownModule()` hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule).

Comment: Thanks Martijn! `setUpModule` and `tearDownModule`  did the task admirably.  Don't know how I missed those.